# How do i get my nav links responsive but also not extend past 50%?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to turn a PSD into a website for practice, and I am trying to figure out the best way to turn the nav into code.

[Here is what I am trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ldd.jpg)

HTML

```
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <img src="img/icon.png" alt="" class="logo">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Places</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Boards</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    justify-content: space-around
}
.main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    font-family: "LeagueSpartan";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
    letter-spacing: 8px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet, now you just need to update `font-family` to get the result that you want!

```css
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    justify-content: space-around
}
.main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    font-family: "LeagueSpartan";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
}
.main-nav ul li {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.main-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="main-nav">
        <img src="img/icon.png" alt="" class="logo">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Places</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Boards</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Hope this helps!